# Cannot send email address to office 365 email address

Tags: php, email-server, microsoft-office-365

i have a web page used to send direct email set of email addresses stored on my database . all email addresses are receiving my emails fine except office 365 users so my question is do i need extra config on my server to send emails or what.
my hosting is goDaddy

Comment: Does Office365 accept your E-Mails? Do you send on port 587 via SSL?

Comment: What does the log say?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your configuration.  If you are attempting to relay messages thru Office 365, you need to send the request secured with TLS and provide active user credentials to authenticate to the system.

If you are using an internal SMTP relay server to send to Office 365 - then that server needs to be the one to authenticate.  Now if you relaying messages via MX (i.e. over the internet) then O365 should be receiving the messages. You can do some of the following to track it down:

1. Check the Office 365 email logs.   If the system is processing the message it should show up here.  However if your IP is blacklisted - this won't be the case.
2. If your IP is blacklisted on any list O365 uses (not published),
   than messages are rejected outright. There is nothing the recipients
   can do, you have to get it unblocked
3. Run a test to O365 but make sure the replyto address is a real
   mailbox.  Evaluate the NDR being returned.  O365 is very good at
   detailing why messages are not delivered and how to fix them.